# Loading children asynchronously on Ember returning HTTP 401, Route doesn't catch error

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, ember-data, http-status-code-401

I develop my app to load record's children asynchronously, modifying payload to include 'links'. I also override the error action in every Route to handle the error when i get an error from the backend (401, 403, 500...). The problem is, I can't catch the error if it refers to the async loading of model's children. Is this a bug from Ember Data? Is there any other way to catch this errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a model fails to load during a transition the error catching is done by the router, not by Ember Data.  Fetching async records is handled outside of the router, so it's unaware that a record has failed to load.

If you know you're going to fetch the async models you could fetch them in the `afterModel` hook and return them to it, which will crash the entire transition if this is what you're looking for.

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bar: DS.belongsTo('bar', {async: true})
});

App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('foo', 1);
  },
  afterModel: function(model, transition){
    return model.get('bar'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, @kingpin2k.

How would I do that? I'm afraid I don't understand your solution.

Comment: I tossed up an example, this would block until bar is fetched